# Rlocation, LAUNCHER ERROR while doing bazel run command

Tags: java, scala, bazel, bazel-rules

Im getting the following error while doing bazel run command.

`LAUNCHER ERROR: Rlocation failed on external\local_jdk\bin\java.exe, path doesn't exist in MANIFEST file`

Bazel build seems to work fine but the run commands throws this error.

I do have java installed with version

```java
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.1.1+2-6)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.1.1+2-6, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Bazel build command returns successful message - bazel build scalaBinaryName

Appreciate any help or hint on this issue. Im searching in the dark here.

Comment: Please provide more context - what command did you type - what happens before this message appears?

Comment: bazel run applicationName

Comment: before this message it shows -> INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action

Answer (score 0):

Follow the installation guide [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/install-windows.html). You need to install MSYS2 x86_64 as described in the install manual.

Comment: well the build is finishing successfully. so would this still be the issue? Anyway I tried installing it as mentioned in the documentation and added it to PATH, still facing the issue.

Comment: I'm in the same situation as OP. The issue isn't a missing tool, it seems like a pathing issue and I can't figure it out.